# Verilog ,cannot be assigned more than one value

Tags: verilog

I am New to Verilog, I am trying to make a CPLD power up protection logic, it actually use a bunch of Timer to validate the state machine. I have a CPLD with 1Mhz OSC, and I am trying to make a 15s timer, I figure the code, but it have compile error, says **"cannot be assigned more than one value".** I knew this mean the signal net has been control by two different signal, but it has a error line shows

Error (12014): Net "Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input", which fans out to "Timer[0]", cannot be assigned more than one value
    Error (12015): Net is fed by "clk_div:d|clk_out"
    Error (12015): Net is fed by "Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input"

**`why "Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input" is connected to itself??`**

```
  module PowerUpProtection(

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Inputs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    input wire Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input,
    input wire Clock,
    input wire Reset,
    input wire Input1_Check_precharge_status,
    input wire Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check,
    input wire Input3_powerUp_validation,

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Outputs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    output reg Output1_Relay_Swtich_For_Main_PowerSource,
    output reg Output2_Switch_On_and_Charge_CAP,
    output reg Output3_Switch_On_and_power_SoM,
    output reg Output4_Press_and_hold_the_powerSource,
    output reg Output5_Switch_on_relay_when_CPLD_powerup
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    );


    // this is a Module Instantiation, connect the inputs and output from different module within CPLD.
    clk_div d(
        .Clock  (Clock),
        .reset(Reset),
        .clk_out(Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input)
    );
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // State Encoding 
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    localparam STATE_0_Initial = 4'd0,
                  STATE_1_Press_and_hold = 4'd1,
                  STATE_2_Power_up = 4'd2,
                  STATE_3_Check_Switches = 4'd3,
                 STATE_4_SwtichSafe_StartPreCharging = 4'd4,
                  STATE_5_ERROR = 4'd5,
                  STATE_6_CAP_is_Charging = 4'd6,
                  STATE_7_Charging_End_SwitchOn_MainPower = 4'd7,
                  STATE_8_PowerSupply_Ready = 4'd8,
                  ERROR_9_TIME_OUT = 4'd9,
                  STATE_10_Precharge_Switch_is_broken = 4'd10,
                  STATE_11_Main_power_switch_is_broken = 4'd11,
                  STATE_12_Both_switches_are_broken = 4'd12,
                  STATE_13_PlaceHolder = 4'd13,
                  STATE_14_PlaceHolder = 4'd14,
                  STATE_15_PlaceHolder = 4'd15;       
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // State reg Declarations
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    reg [3:0] CurrentState = 4'd0;
    reg [3:0] NextState = 4'd0;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Timer reg Declarations
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    reg [8:0] Timer = 0;
    reg enable_the_counter = 0;  // the boolean to enbale the counter.
    reg clear_the_counter = 0;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Outputs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    always@(*) begin
        // clear for the initial state.
        reg Output1_Relay_Swtich_For_Main_PowerSource = 0;
        reg Output2_Switch_On_and_Charge_CAP = 0;
        reg Output3_Switch_On_and_power_SoM = 0;
        reg Output4_Press_and_hold_the_powerSource = 0;
        reg Output5_Switch_on_relay_when_CPLD_powerup = 0;

        case (CurrentState)
            STATE_1_Press_and_hold : begin
                Output4_Press_and_hold_the_powerSource = 1;
            end

            STATE_2_Power_up        : begin
                Output5_Switch_on_relay_when_CPLD_powerup = 1;
            end

            STATE_3_Check_Switches   : begin
                Output2_Switch_On_and_Charge_CAP = 1;
            end 

            STATE_4_SwtichSafe_StartPreCharging : begin
                Output2_Switch_On_and_Charge_CAP = 1;
            end

            STATE_5_ERROR : begin
                // to be determined
            end

            STATE_6_CAP_is_Charging :  begin 
                // wait for the charging to be complete
            end

            STATE_7_Charging_End_SwitchOn_MainPower : begin
                Output1_Relay_Swtich_For_Main_PowerSource =1;
            end

            STATE_8_PowerSupply_Ready : begin
                Output5_Switch_on_relay_when_CPLD_powerup = 0;
                Output3_Switch_On_and_power_SoM = 1;
            end
        endcase
    end
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------   



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Synchronous State-Transition always@(posedge Clock) block
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    always@(posedge Clock) begin
        if (Reset) CurrentState <= STATE_0_Initial;
        else CurrentState <= NextState;
    end
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // conditional State-Trasnsition Always@(*) block
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    always@(*) begin
        NextState = CurrentState;
        case (CurrentState)

            STATE_0_Initial :begin
                NextState = STATE_1_Press_and_hold;
            end

            STATE_1_Press_and_hold : begin
                if (Input3_powerUp_validation) NextState = STATE_2_Power_up;
            end

            STATE_2_Power_up : begin
                if (Input3_powerUp_validation) NextState = STATE_3_Check_Switches;
            end

            STATE_3_Check_Switches : begin 
                if (Input1_Check_precharge_status == 0 && Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check == 1 )
                    begin
                    NextState = STATE_4_SwtichSafe_StartPreCharging;
                    enable_the_counter = 1; //Start to count the time.
                    end

                else if (Input1_Check_precharge_status == 1 && Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check == 1)
                    begin
                    NextState = STATE_10_Precharge_Switch_is_broken;
                    end

                else if (Input1_Check_precharge_status == 0 && Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check == 0)
                    begin
                    NextState = STATE_11_Main_power_switch_is_broken;
                    end

                else
                    begin 
                    NextState = STATE_12_Both_switches_are_broken;
                    end

            end

            STATE_4_SwtichSafe_StartPreCharging : begin

                if (Input1_Check_precharge_status == 1 && Timer <= 300) //equals to 15 seconds
                    NextState = STATE_6_CAP_is_Charging;

                else if (Timer > 300)
                    NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;  //Time out Error
                    clear_the_counter = 1;
                    enable_the_counter = 0;
            end

            STATE_6_CAP_is_Charging : begin

                if (Input1_Check_precharge_status == 0 && Timer <= 300) 
                    begin
                        NextState = STATE_7_Charging_End_SwitchOn_MainPower;
                        clear_the_counter = 1; // timer is over, clear the  counter.
                        enable_the_counter =0;
                    end
                else if (Timer > 300)
                    begin
                        NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;  //Time out Error
                        clear_the_counter = 1;
                        enable_the_counter = 0;
                    end
            end 

            STATE_7_Charging_End_SwitchOn_MainPower : begin

                //enable the counter again, and count for 50 m seconds.
                enable_the_counter = 1;
                if (Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check ==1)
                        begin
                        if (Timer <=1)
                            NextState = STATE_7_Charging_End_SwitchOn_MainPower; // if time is not 50 ms yet, go back to itself current  state
                        else
                            NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;  //Time out Error
                            clear_the_counter = 1;
                            enable_the_counter = 0;
                        end
                else if (Input2_MainPowerSwitch_relay_status_Check == 0)  // if the switch is ready right away, that is best.

                        begin
                        NextState = STATE_8_PowerSupply_Ready; 
                        end
                else 
                        NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;  //Time out Error
                        clear_the_counter = 1;
                        enable_the_counter = 0;
            end

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Place-Holder transition.
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            STATE_13_PlaceHolder : begin
                NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;
            end

            STATE_14_PlaceHolder : begin
                NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;
            end
            STATE_15_PlaceHolder : begin
                NextState = STATE_5_ERROR;
            end


        endcase
    end 

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 50 m Seconds counter block, make the osc into 20 HZ by implement the counter
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    always@(posedge Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input or posedge Reset or posedge clear_the_counter ) begin
        if (Reset == 1 || clear_the_counter == 1) 
            begin
                Timer = 0;
            end
        else
            begin 
                if (enable_the_counter) 
                Timer <= Timer + 1'b1;
            end
    end
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------



endmodule





    //clock devider, the board has a 10 M hz osc, 
//so I create this code to count 200000 times 
//for each posedge and that equalle to 50 m-second.
// if count until 50 m-second, this clk_out will output one positive edge.

module clk_div(
    input Clock,
    input reset,
    output reg clk_out
    );
    parameter diver = 99999;
    reg [23:0] count;//just for 99999 or warning

    always@(posedge Clock or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
        begin
            count <= 0;
            clk_out <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if(count == diver)
        begin
            clk_out <= ~clk_out;
            count <= 0;
        end
        else
        begin
            count <= count + 1'b1;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` is in input, meaning it should be driven by any module instantiating `PowerUpProtection` (or some pin if its the top module), thus the first driver. The second driver is the `clk_div` module `d`. Here, `Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` is connected to output `clk_out`.

From the code, it seems this signal should be driven from the clock divider, so you should probably remove this signal from the inputs and just declare it a `reg` in the module body. Or possibly mux the signal so you can decide how to drive it (`assign Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input = (mux_Fifty_m_second) ? Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_from_inputs : Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_from_clk_div;` or something).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  In this design, the Top module is **PowerUpProtection**, this module is driven by Clock signal and also by the  ** Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input**, the reason is I want to make the Timer into a single module, so in that way I do not need to define a very long reg, (like reg[32:0] Input), so if in this way, the  ** Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input**has to be a input instead of reg. and for your second suggestion, I am confused, can you help me to explain more detail? what Mux is? is it mean it could decide with signal could drive the input instead of conflict?

Comment: @SamCao Im not sure I understand why `Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` has to be an input to the design when it is already output by the clock divider you have in the module (you already have the external clock coming in from the `Clock` input, from which it seems `Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` is derived). My second suggestion is simply a switch to determine whether `Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` is driven by the clock divider or external pin. Based on everything I understand now, you shouldnt need to do this unless `Fifty_m_second_Devide_Clock_input` is driven from outside.